# Musician wants to know the programming term for this function

Tags: function

My apologies that I don't use always use programming terms in my description - I am a musician who has only dabbled in programming.

Suppose I have a list of numbers named a:

a = (0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12)

and from the list a the following list of numbers is randomly generated to create list b:

b = (4, 7, 5, 7, 9, 11, 9)

Then I want to have "transpositions" (this is a musical term) of list b, such as those shown in lists c, d, and e:

c = (5, 9, 7, 9, 11, 12, 11) or d = (2, 5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 9) or e = (0, 4, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 7)

What do you call this "transposition" of this list of numbers in programming terms, and what bit of programming code would accomplish this task? My best guess is that it has to do with the indexing of the numbers in list a, and when list b is created the indexes of list b are put in a list such as list f:

f = (2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5)

so that the "transposition" is accomplished by adding or subtracting a specific number from each number in list f. For example, the numbers in list c are generated by adding 1 to each of the numbers in list f:

(3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6)

the numbers in list d are generated by subtracting 1 to each of the numbers in list f:

(1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4)

and the numbers in list e are generated by subtracting 2 to each of the index numbers taken from list f:

(0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3)

Or if anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

Comment: Are you just choosing elements at random from `a` and `b` to produce `c`, `d`, and `e`? If you treat `a` and `b` as *multisets*, then `c` et al. might simply be elements constructed from the *sum* of `a` and `b`. (Maybe elements of the powerset of the sum, for whatever analog of powersets exists for multistep.)

Comment: You might have better luck at math.stackexchange.com, as this isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

An operation like "add 1 to every member of this list, to generate a new list" is usually called a *map*.

Comment: But the question itself seems to be nonsense. No rule on earth would get you from your b to your c, etc.